# How do I link and extract events to a session ID in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have multiple users negotiating through a site and I would like to link-up each event to a session ID, then export this into excel for analysis.

I've tried using the "User Explorer" but the exporting from here is pretty poor and I can only access 1 user at a time.

Ideally a table with events as headers and session columns.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack is not a coding service.  Please give it a try and come back and we will be happy to help you fix any issues you may be having.

Comment: Do you want to see sessions or users?

Comment: I'm happy with either; it's specifically the individual's actions that I'm interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs in the User Explorer is not available as custom reports. To pull the type of report you're looking for, you will need to create your own user and session scoped custom dimensions to properly capture this information.